# catch a anchor click from an anchor that is generated by wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently experiencing PHP and Wordpress. I created a test wordpress page on localhost. On the front page I have a link generated by wordpress. Now I'm wondering if its possible to catch the click when this link is clicked using PHP. I thought about using `isset`.

My problem now is that these links don't have a `name` attribute to catch it using `isset`. Or is there an option in wordpress to change that?

Or is there another option to set e.g. `?testlink` at the end of the wordpress links?

Can someone please explain and help me?

Comment: May be set link `href="localhost/test/?testlink"` and use php code `<?php if(isset($_GET['testlink'])){ // code } ?>`

Comment: Ok thank you, this works but what if the link is generated by wordpress? I cannot change a wordpress link, can I?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know wordpress.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the question :)